# Node js writing bulk xml data to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, xml-parsing, node-modules

Need some assistance in node.js. Trying to update about 6000+ records into SQL Server. The records size maybe 5 to 10 MB. The xml records will be sent to the stored procedure which has a `nvarchar(max)` parameter. I am fetching records from a soap API call and push to SQL Server via a stored procedure.

I get an error when I run the below code if the record size is beyond 2000 in xml object. What is best way to send large xml objects of 5 to 10k to a SQL Server stored procedure?

Any nodejs library to handle this? Can nodejs handle such large records update ?

Note: this code will run inside aws lambda

```
var soap = require("strong-soap").soap;
var rfcUrl = https://xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx.asmx?WSDL;


var rfcRequestArgs = {
    UserName:
    Password:
};

var options = {};
console.log("Calling ervice...\n");
soap.createClient(rfcUrl, options, function(err, client) {
  var method = client["GetLocationData"];
  method(rfcRequestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        //'result' is the response body
   
        console.log('RFC Result: \n');
        
        InitializeSQLConnection(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
});

var connection = null;   


function InitializeSQLConnection(LocData)
{
    
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    server: 'ddddddddd',  //update me
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'xxxxxxx', //update me
            password: 'xxxxxxx'  //update me
            
        }
    } ,
    options: {
        // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
        encrypt: false,
        database: 'DBName'  //update me
    }
};  
connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
    if (err) {
        console.log('SQL Connection Failed!');
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
    // If no error, then good to proceed.
    console.log("SQL Server Connected");  
    executeStoredProcedure(LocData);      
});
connection.connect();
   
}

function executeStoredProcedure(LocData)
{   
    console.log("calling executeStoredProcedure");  
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
    var loadTestState = 0;
   
  
        var request = new Request('spname_new', function(err) {    
            connection.close();       
       });
      
        request.addParameter('parameterrecords', TYPES.NVarChar, LocData);      
        request.addOutputParameter('returnVal', TYPES.Int);

        request.on('returnValue', (paramName, value, metadata) => {
            console.log(paramName + ' : ' + value);
        });

        connection.callProcedure(request);
        
        console.log("Called SP");  
}
'''
```